# How do you present One small ViewController on Top of a full screen ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have designed two ViewControllers - VCLarge and VCSmall.  VCSmall is freeform.
When I display VCSmall on top of VCLarge - I shows full screen.
So I play tricks and change the formSize in ViewWillAppear - The VCLarge still does show (I see black)

FYI - I do this when the ViewControllers are in a storyboard and have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to present your viewcontroller like UIPopover controller like below...
Please see this OpenSource FPPopver.
It is perfect and works fine.
Very easy to implement.
https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover

```
YourViewController *controller = [[YourViewController alloc] init]; 

//our popover
FPPopoverController *popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:controller]; 

[popover presentPopoverFromView:okButton];
```

That's all.
If you want to get rid off that ARROW tip, you can do that too!

Answer (score -1):

you use `[UIView addSubview]` to show it on top of VCLarge.
For example, if you're within VCLarge, you would do something like this:

`UIView *smallView = [VCSmall alloc] init... 
[self.view addSubview:smallView];`

You can adjust the size and or position of smallView using appropriate CGRects for smallView.

Comment: `UIViewController *smallView = [VCSmall alloc] init…]; 
[self.view addSubview:smallView.view];`

Comment: I want a modal behavior.  This just adds the view.  That is not what I want.  My VCSmall implements a form like behavior.  Also I don't understand why this works as desired in storyboards but not with individual VCControllers.